# external usb 3.0 hub not responding

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have a "Zerolemon" external usb 3.0 hub (This one: [https://www.amazon.com/ZeroLemon-Charging-Switches-Indicators-Adapter/dp/B00NSE1OGY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NSE1OGY)), and Ubuntu 22.04. Ubuntu is not recognizing it, with these errors:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i USB
[ 1138.097664] usb 1-8.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1138.097664] usb 1-8.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1159.075292] usb 1-8.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 1159.196624] usb 1-8.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812, bcdDevice=90.90
[ 1159.196637] usb 1-8.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1159.196641] usb 1-8.2: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[ 1159.196645] usb 1-8.2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[ 1159.198124] hub 1-8.2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1159.511260] usb 1-8.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 1159.738487] usb 1-8.2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1159.943457] usb 1-8.2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1160.155312] usb 1-8.2.1: device not accepting address 18, error -71
[ 1161.779275] usb 1-8.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[ 1161.871407] usb 1-8.2.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1162.075414] usb 1-8.2.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1162.275291] usb 1-8.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 1162.367314] usb 1-8.2.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1162.571318] usb 1-8.2.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 1162.679453] usb 1-8.2-port4: attempt power cycle
[ 1163.695500] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.695644] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.695788] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.695790] usb 1-8.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 1163.695932] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 1163.696169] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.696299] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.696437] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.696566] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.696696] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot reset (err = -71)
[ 1163.696698] usb 1-8.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 1163.696830] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 1163.696868] usb 1-8.2-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 1163.697001] usb 1-8.2-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[ 1163.697478] usb 1-8.2: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 1163.697481] usb 1-8.2: Failed to suspend device, error -19
[ 1168.933946] usb 2-3.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1169.145908] usb 2-3.2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1169.351144] usb 2-3.2: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[ 1169.679275] usb 2-3.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

I'm not sure what these errors mean or how to fix it. Searching online did not find anything useful.

**UPDATE:**
When I plug in a USB Flash drive to the hub I get these errors now:

```
[20857.928955] usb 2-3.3.4: device not accepting address 43, error -62
[20857.929211] usb 2-3.3-port4: attempt power cycle
[20868.929460] usb 2-3.3.4: device not accepting address 44, error -62
[20873.681588] usb 1-8.3.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 66
[20879.941960] usb 2-3.3.4: device not accepting address 45, error -62
[20879.948690] usb 2-3.3-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[20879.948778] usb 2-3.3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
[20879.955782] usb 2-3.3-port4: cannot disable (err = -71)
[20879.955818] usb 2-3.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 33
[20879.974187] usb 2-3.3: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[20879.981185] usb 2-3.3: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[20880.254403] usb 1-8.3: reset high-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[20880.374240] usb 1-8.3: device firmware changed
[20880.374475] usb 1-8.3: USB disconnect, device number 64
[20880.374480] usb 1-8.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 65
[20881.158013] usb 1-8.3: new high-speed USB device number 67 using xhci_hcd
[20881.176211] usb 2-3.3: USB disconnect, device number 28
[20881.279032] usb 1-8.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0812, bcdDevice= 1.90
[20881.279044] usb 1-8.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[20881.279049] usb 1-8.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[20881.280556] hub 1-8.3:1.0: USB hub found
[20881.574092] usb 1-8.3.1: new high-speed USB device number 68 using xhci_hcd
[20881.654128] usb 1-8.3.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[20882.302242] usb 1-8.3.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[20882.385689] usb 1-8.3: USB disconnect, device number 67
[20882.414518] usb 1-8.3-port1: attempt power cycle
[20882.414528] usb 1-8.3-port1: failed to disable port power
```

If I plug the same flash drive into a USB plug on the front of the case it works with no issues.

Comment: Does it work under Windows on the same PC?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have another computer that has Windows 7. I plugged it in there, and Windows recognized the hub. It tried to install the device drivers but encountered an error. I think something is probably wrong with the hub. I plugged the hub back into the Ubuntu computer and I get errors when I try to plug a device into the hub. I will update the original post with the new errors.

Comment: Your own PC's USB port could be malfunctioning, so checking on a different PC is not representative of your PC or this device.